# finding a position in loop can find the highest number but need its position

Tags: matlab

i have this code that i made it prints  out "number" and the "value" where value is the order it came in which i obtained from a loop.

i was able to get the highest number from "numbers but can't find a way to print out its "VALUE"  or which position its in for example:

```
number =

     3     5     5     4

Value 1 has 3  number 
Value 2 has 6  number 
Value 3 has 5  number 
Value 4 has 4  number 

highest =    6
```

i want my out put to say

value 2 has 6 number

it can find 6 easily by using max(number) but how can i get its position in the loop?
and what is the case if we have 2 numbers equal could in say both the positions

this is my code

```
number
len= length(number);

%for aligning and display loop
x=1;
while x<=len
    fprintf('Value %x has %d  number \n',x,number(x))
    x=x+1;
end 

highest = max(number)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using,

```
[high, pos] = max(number);
```

instead of `highest = max(number)`;

where `high` is the largest number and `pos` is the value you required.